# Get aspect ratio for lat-long plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, aspect-ratio, cartography

I know R has various ways to plot maps properly with projections.  But just for a quick 'good enough' result using base functions, is there a function to calculate the aspect ratio for a particular latitude that if provided to R's typical `asp` arguments will approximate the right plot?  i.e. Something equivalent to ggplot2's [coord_quickmap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/coord_quickmap.html) method.  Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're doing map plots in base (i.e. where you're getting the data from)?

Comment: Also, by default, `maps::map` will `use a rectangular projection with the aspect ratio chosen so that longitude and latitude scales are equivalent at the center of the picture`. Lemme post an example of how that's pretty much equivalent to `coord_quickmap`.

Comment: Plot example `plot(state.center$x, state.center$y, asp=1.6)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what `coord_quickmap` provides is close enough for you, then you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

# shamelessly stolen from coord_quickmap

map_aspect = function(x, y) {
  x.center <- sum(range(x)) / 2
  y.center <- sum(range(y)) / 2
  x.dist <- ggplot2:::dist_central_angle(x.center + c(-0.5, 0.5), rep(y.center, 2))
  y.dist <- ggplot2:::dist_central_angle(rep(x.center, 2), y.center + c(-0.5, 0.5))
  y.dist / x.dist
}
```

What `ggplot` would do:

```
ggplot(data.frame(state.center)) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

Same thing, now, in base:

```
plot(state.center$x, state.center$y,
     asp=map_aspect(state.center$x, state.center$y))
```

[image]

Remember, though, that `coord_quickmap` (and, hence, the calculated ratio from it) was designed for *small* areas. I post some resources for being able to pick map projections here: [here](http://rud.is/b/2015/07/24/a-path-towards-easier-map-projection-machinations-with-ggplot2/) which will work great with `spTransform` & base).

Comment: Spot on!  Slightly confused why the longitude inputs are necessary but hey.  `ggplot(data.frame(state.center)) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + coord_fixed(ratio = ar)` will demonstrate it's the exact same plot